# How to update webview without using the Google Play store?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, webview

I have an Android 5.1 device, where I have full root access. For this device I have written a **cordova application** and installed it as a **system app**. It is working good, however the webview-version of Android 5.1 is very old and unfortunately has a few bugs.

I know that you can update the webview with the playstore, but unfortunately the device does not have the google apps and therefore I am not able to update the webview with the playstore.

So my question is:
**How can I update the system webview without google playstore?**

I already tried it with a rather naive approach, which unfortunately killed my application:

I have downloaded the latest `webview.apk` from the playstore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=de)

Then I did:

```
adb remount
adb push webview.apk /system/webview/
adb reboot
```

Now I get errors when I try to start my cordova application and the app itself doesn't show up anymore:

```
I/CordovaActivity( 1931): Apache Cordova native platform version 6.1.1 is starting
D/CordovaActivity( 1931): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
E/WebViewFactory( 1931): Failed to list WebView package libraries for loadNativeLibrary
E/WebViewFactory( 1931): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.android.webview
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:281)
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewNativeLibraryPaths(WebViewFactory.java:282)
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.loadNativeLibrary(WebViewFactory.java:397)
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:103)
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2194)
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2189)
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2248)
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3595)
E/WebViewFactory( 1931):        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3689)
```

**How is the correct way to update the webview.apk without google playstore?**

Comment: Download latest webview.apk from www.apkmirror.com

Comment: I already have the apk... the problem is how to install it

Comment: Don't forget to reboot after replacing a system `.apk`, so the Dalvik cache gets rebuilt (remember that "updating apps…" hint on first boot?).

Comment: Yes I made a reboot - it also says so in the question. "`adb reboot`"

Answer (score 5):

The Google WebView application is ***very*** different from regular ones. You **cannot** use Package Installer to install or update it in a common way. You must do it yourself (As for my Lollipop 5.1.1).
Here's the way I've done it several times. Run in a root shell. You may need `busybox` for `unzip` (or do it with a file manager).

```
#!/system/bin/sh
rm -r /data/app/com.google.android.webview*
mkdir /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1
cd /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1
cp /path/to/your/webview.apk ./base.apk
unzip base.apk 'lib/armeabi-v7a'
mv lib/armeabi-v7a lib/arm
# Do the following 2 lines only if you're on an ARM64 ROM
unzip base.apk 'lib/arm64-v8a'
mv lib/arm64-v8a lib/arm
#
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find . -exec chown 1000.1000 {} +
```

Alternatively, you can try creating directory `/system/priv-app/WebView` and put the new APK there. **Remember to get rid of the old one**.

Answer (score 3):

You try to update "com.google.android.webview", but your system uses "com.android.webview" version.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace `com.android.webview` with `com.google.android.webview` since they are two different packages and the system's default webview package name is hard-coded in `framework-res.apk`. Please see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/139415/284780 for explanation and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233282/284780 for solution.

Comment: Dude... the question has been answered 4 years ago with the exact same contents of your answer.

Comment: @michael-b I wouldn't say exactly the same since the above answers did not mention that you have to edit the configuration value in Android framework to switch to another webview package. Your default webview package is com.android.webview and the one you wanted to use is com.google.android.webview. There is no way you can do that without modifying the Android framework.